# Adding/removing a point in $L^2$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there an (isometric) isomorphism $L^2(\mathbb R)\cong L^2(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$? More generally, for a measure space $M$, do we have an isomorphism $L^2(M)\cong L^2(M \setminus N)$ for a subset $N\subset M$ of zero measure?

In the case of $L^2(\mathbb R)\cong L^2(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$ I thought about the following: $L^2(\mathbb R)\to L^2(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$ given by restriction, and $L^2(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})\to L^2(\mathbb R)$ by $f\mapsto g$ with $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=a$ for an arbitrary fixed $a\in\mathbb R$. That should be an isomorphism because every function in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is in fact an equivalence class and thus "coincides" with a function of value $a$ at $0$, because $\{0\}$ has zero measure. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It means that you should include your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: thanks, I added some thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and a natural surjective isometry is the map $[f]\mapsto \left[\left. f\right\rvert_{M\setminus N}\right]$ (provided you mean $N$ to have zero *measure* instead of the unwarranted *Lebesgue* measure). Same holds for all $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: thanks! yes, I meant "measure", not necessarily Lebesgue measure, sorry for the confusion. does the inverse of this map look as indicated in my question?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.